# How do I focus Word document after using userform in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a small userform as interface to various VBA functions. I use these commonly for document automation like inserting tables formatted in certain way etc.

This works great, but I would like to have a workflow where I place the cursor at desired place, click the function, and **can continue writing**. Currently the form always keeps the focus after being clicked.  The form is not modal.

So in image below, I have focus on (1) but want focus on (2) after VBA sub in form has completed.

[image: image showing cut of VBA userform in front of inserted element (tooltip)]

I did try ending the macro with `ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.SetFocus` which does not make a difference.

I could of course close the form after every macro, but I use it commonly, so this would be less preferred.

Comment: Please, use `Word.Application.Activate`. It should do what you need...

Comment: Not the answert to your question but propably an enhancement for your workflow: Maybe it would be worth to create a custom ribbon or custom context menu and place the functions there instead of using a user form ...

Comment: @Ike part of the form is input of some variables which I don't think ribbons support. Otherwise, you are correct.

Comment: @FaneDuru make this an answer and I will accept it. Your solution worked. Thank you.

Comment: sure - you can have inputs (edit box, drop down) in the ribbon (s. here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/7b552756-a970-466d-b7c2-ee5bbe171e34) But you are right - it depends on the amount of data if this is really a better user experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try one of the two ways. Both of them have to work:

```
   Word.Application.Activate
   AppActivate ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Caption
```